# Litecoin/Bitcoin how to get target using javascript?

Tags: javascript, math, hex, bitcoin

i'm almost done in implementating litecoin/bitcoin miner in js just for fun, i just don't know ho to find target hex. As docs says, it is max / difficulty, but if difficulty is (for example) 62, how can I perform a division between 0x00000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF and 62?

Comment: parseInt('0x00000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF',16)/62?

Comment: _JavaScript_ will have errors with numbers this big. Also, `0x000..etc` is already a hex literal (the `0x` lets the interpreter know, e.g. `0xA === 10; // true`), so just use it like any other number.

Comment: How can I have a workaround for numbers so big? Any suggestions? :/

Answer (score -1):

Do you just mean how to divide a hex number  by a decimal number?

```
parseInt('0x00000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF',16)/62?
```

Comment: I also thinked about it, but it seems not to be the solution for the litecoin/bitcoin network. By the way, number is too small and it is rounded.